# Find command not working in for loop

Tags: bash, find

I have list of filename , I want to provide those files one by one to find command so that i can get the path.
I have use the for loop and take all filename in variable using cat command, Then pass them to find command through variable one by one but its not working.
can any one guide me?

```
for f in $(cat filelist.txt)
do 
find /home/abc/ -type f -name "$f"
done;
```

I am not getting any error but not getting output either I tried putting output in variable as well but no luck.

Comment: And the script you use is?

Comment: Sorry guys , this in linux bash.

Comment: Please show the code in your question that you've tried. Format it with the `{}` button to mark it up as code. What happened when you ran it? How did that differ from what you expected? Did you get any errors?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Please would you show a few lines from your `filelist.txt`. (Change parts of the values if you must but make sure the shape of the data is exactly the same as your actual data, as otherwise we will answer for the wrong issue.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the files whose name are any of the ones stored in `filelist.txt` one per line, one easy way is to use `zsh`'s `globbing`:

```
names=( ${(f)"$(<filelist.txt)"} ) &&
  (( $#names )) &&
  print -rC1 -- /home/abc/**/${(~j[|])names}(D.)
```

As to why your approach doesn't work, it's not immediately obvious, though there are few problems with it:

- In `bash`, that unquoted `$(cat filelist.txt)` invokes split+glob (split only in zsh) on the contents of `filelist.txt`. With the default value of `$IFS` (which is used for the split part), that will split on newline characters but also on space and tab. So if you have a `my file.txt` line in there, it will look for files called `my` and files called `file.txt` instead of files called `my file.txt`
- If there is a file called `*` in `filelist.txt`, the *glob* part will expand it to the list of files in the directory the script is being called from.
- Also `-name '*'` will not look for a file called `*`, but will report every file as what's passed to `-name` is taken as a pattern. You'd need to escape the `[`, `?`, `*` and `\` with `\` to disable the wildcard operators.

Now, your problem may also be that:

- `filelist.txt` is in MSDOS text format with CRLF delimiters instead of LF. You'd run `dos2unix` on it to fix it.
- that you have file paths in `filelist.txt` (such as `dir/file.txt`). `-name` matches on the file name only, so would never match on that.

Here, instead of a loop, you could use GNU `xargs`:

```
xargs -rd'\n' -a filelist.txt -I NAME find /home/abc/ -name NAME -type f
```

But that still means crawling the whole of `/home/abc/` for each file name, which is inefficient.

Instead, you could do:

```
xargs -rd'\n' -n200 -a <(sed 's/[*?\\[]/\\&/g' filelist.txt) sh -c '
  for name do
    set -- -o -name "$name"
    shift
  done
  shift
  find /home/abc/ \( "$@" \) -type f' sh
```

Where we call `find /home/abc/ \( -name name1 -o -name name2... \) -type f` with up to 200 names in one `find` invocation, which means potentially 200 as few crawlings of `/home/abc`. Not as good as `zsh` which does only 1 in any case, but still a lot better.

We also use `sed` to escape the wildcard characters in the names. You could also through in a `dos2unix` in there.

Comment: This is resolved , the issue was with filelist. actually was was saving that file on windows n then accessing at linux . I just create a new file in linux n copy the list . Then everything works well. Thanks for help .

Answer (score -1):

Try also

```
find -iname $(sed -z 's/\n$//; s/\n/ -o -iname /g' list.txt)
```

The `sed -z` looks for lines terminated by a `\000` character which should not exist in *nix text files, so it loads the entire file into memory. Then removes the trailing `<NL>` char, and substitutes the residual ones with `-o -iname` so `find` get served a long list of `or`ed filenames.